# Attribute inputmode : "obsolete since HTML5.2", How to replace it?

Tags: html, input, user-experience

MDN is saying that the attribute inputmode is obsolete since HTML 5.2.

But, even if not a lot implemented, this attribute is really useful, so by what I have to replace it ?

Most of my usage is on mobiles, where type="number" is not always displaying the good keyboard. Even with pattern defined.

Link to MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: It's not "not a lot implemented", it's completely not implemented anywhere, and hasn't been despite having been in the spec for so many years. This seems a strange question to be asking only today.

Comment: It's implemented on iphone/ios and android. It works for exemple on Chrome on Oneplus 5/One and Safari Phone 6S. Without this on these devices, the keyboard displayed is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3290

According to that, Chrome and Firefox are planning to implement inputmode in the not too distant future. At which point, the W3C spec will no doubt catch up. The W3C HTML specs tend to be more conservative in including not-yet-implemented features than the WHATWG Living spec, where [`inputmode` is still defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-inputmode).

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is implementing it right now.

To be released in Chrome 66.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6225984592281600

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)